# Get cursor position in selection - relative to document

Tags: javascript, caret

**Sample**

> This is some text in an **editable** div. This can span over multiple lines, paragraphs and 
>   so on and so forth. What I want to do is find the relative position of the caret **right here**. Meaning, the caret is positioned {top:'5px', left:'250px'}, relative to the div or the document.

The idea is to then provide drop downs with options. Is this possible directly or will I have to concoct a solution based on the `div line-height, padding,.. + caret position` etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this demo from rangy. Maybe just what you are looking for:

https://github.com/timdown/rangy/blob/master/demos/position.html

If you look at the code, you'll be able to see this:

```
var startPos = rangy.getSelection().getStartDocumentPos(); // get x, y of selection/cursor
```

and then you can use `startPos.x` and `startPos.y`

Comment: I can find the selection alright, but what I want is the its position relative to the body. Consider it this way, what if the caret was the mouse pointer? Then at that point, I'd have its position - left, top, etc

Comment: The above demo does not just get the selection but in fact gets the position (x, y) relative to the body of the current selection. It then appends 2 elements to mark that position.

Comment: ahh, now that's more like it. Thank you

Comment: My pleasure. FYI, i found it online a couple months back when i was trying to implement a custom auto-complete on a text-area.. i guess kind of like what you're trying to achieve now..

Comment: Link is broken bro

Comment: @Rust - Thank you for pointing out. I've corrected it. 
Rangy got moved to github. Hence the breakage.

Answer (score 1):

I've dug through the code of Rangy (it's awesome! but an overkill to include it wholly in my use case), and as long as someone doesn't need full cross-browser compatibility, she may use a native one-liner:

`var pos = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects()[0]`

and then you'll have available `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` on `pos` *(okay, I lied - not a truly one-liner, it has to be wrapped to check if there's some range).*

I just need it to work with Firefox so it's enough for me.

Summary:

- Works fully in Firefox 17 / Chrome 23 (**also for just tracking the caret**, without having real selection,
  and without having to enable caret browsing)
- Note however that when you click on an empty fragment of the page (not on any text),
  *you will in fact move the caret somewhere* (enable caret browsing -- <kbd>F7</kbd> in Firefox -- to see where).
  It's usually end of paragraph -- if you click next to it, or the closest text just above the cursor --
  when you click between the paragraphs.
- In Opera 12, works only if there's a non-empty selection.
- Doesn't work on IE8, haven't checked on IE9 nor IE10.

Demo (doesn't work on JSFiddle, so I dump it here in entirety):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var getSelectionTopLeft = function (){
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var rangePos, x, y;
        if(selection.rangeCount) {
            rangePos = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects()[0];
            // you can get also right and bottom here if you like
            x = parseInt(rangePos.left);
            y = parseInt(rangePos.top);
            console && console.log("found selection at: x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
        }else{
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            console && console.log("no selections found");
        }
        return {x: x, y: y};
    }
    var move = function (offsetX, offsetY){
        var coords = getSelectionTopLeft();
        var square = document.getElementById('square');
        square.style.left = (coords.x + offsetX) + 'px';
        square.style.top = (coords.y + offsetY) + 'px';
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #square {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:10px; height:10px; background-color:red;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Caret position test</h1>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <button onclick="move(5, 5)">move the square 5px/5px below the caret</button>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Curabitur tempor pharetra iaculis. Ut tempor mauris et ligula
    aliquam sed venenatis dui pharetra. Duis dictum rutrum venenatis.
    Cras ut lorem justo.</p>

    <p>Nam vehicula elit tincidunt nibh elementum venenatis. Duis a facilisis sem.
    Morbi luctus porttitor feugiat. Nunc feugiat augue eu tortor interdum fermentum
    a tincidunt felis.</p>
</body>
</html>
```